# Unblock the navigation from a Popup

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this script from Quantcast that shows a popup that blocks the navigation until the visitor accepts the cookies. You can see how it works on this website if you enter with a European IP:
https://hipertextual.com/

However, I would like to NOT BLOCK the navigation of the user, I mean, that the popup shows up, but the user can keep scrolling the page, etc.

I have seen a website doing this: https://www.meneame.net/c/24807808

Can someone tell me how should I edit the script in order to do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript" async=true>
var elem = document.createElement('script');
elem.src = 'https://quantcast.mgr.consensu.org/cmp.js';
elem.async = true;
elem.type = "text/javascript";
var scpt = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
scpt.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, scpt);
(function() {
var gdprAppliesGlobally = false;
function addFrame() {
    if (!window.frames['__cmpLocator']) {
    if (document.body) {
        var body = document.body,
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.style = 'display:none';
        iframe.name = '__cmpLocator';
        body.appendChild(iframe);
    } else {
        // In the case where this stub is located in the head,
        // this allows us to inject the iframe more quickly than
        // relying on DOMContentLoaded or other events.
        setTimeout(addFrame, 5);
    }
    }
}
addFrame();
function cmpMsgHandler(event) {
    var msgIsString = typeof event.data === "string";
    var json;
    if(msgIsString) {
    json = event.data.indexOf("__cmpCall") != -1 ?       JSON.parse(event.data) : {};
    } else {
    json = event.data;
    }
    if (json.__cmpCall) {
    var i = json.__cmpCall;
    window.__cmp(i.command, i.parameter, function(retValue, success) {
        var returnMsg = {"__cmpReturn": {
        "returnValue": retValue,
        "success": success,
        "callId": i.callId
        }};
        event.source.postMessage(msgIsString ?
        JSON.stringify(returnMsg) : returnMsg, '*');
    });
    }
}
window.__cmp = function (c) {
    var b = arguments;
    if (!b.length) {
    return __cmp.a;
    }
    else if (b[0] === 'ping') {
    b[2]({"gdprAppliesGlobally": gdprAppliesGlobally,
        "cmpLoaded": false}, true);
    } else if (c == '__cmp')
    return false;
    else {
    if (typeof __cmp.a === 'undefined') {
        __cmp.a = [];
    }
    __cmp.a.push([].slice.apply(b));
    }
}
window.__cmp.gdprAppliesGlobally = gdprAppliesGlobally;
window.__cmp.msgHandler = cmpMsgHandler;
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('message', cmpMsgHandler, false);
}
else {
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', cmpMsgHandler);
}
})();
window.__cmp('init', {
        'Language': 'es',
    'Initial Screen Title Text': 'Tu privacidad es importante para nosotros',
    'Initial Screen Reject Button Text': 'No acepto',
    'Initial Screen Accept Button Text': 'Acepto',
    'Initial Screen Purpose Link Text': 'Más información',
    'Purpose Screen Title Text': 'Tu privacidad es importante para nosotros',
    'Purpose Screen Body Text': 'Puedes configurar tus preferencias y elegir como quieres que tus datos sean utilizados para los siguientes propósitos. Puedes elegir configurar tus preferencias solo con nosotros independientemente del resto de nuestros partners. Cada propósito tiene una descripción para que puedas saber como nosotros y nuestros partners utilizamos tus datos',
    'Purpose Screen Enable All Button Text': 'Habilitar todo',
    'Purpose Screen Vendor Link Text': 'Ver lista completa de partners',
    'Purpose Screen Cancel Button Text': 'Cancelar',
    'Purpose Screen Save and Exit Button Text': 'Guardar y salir',
    'Vendor Screen Title Text': 'Tu privacidad es importante para nosotros',
    'Vendor Screen Body Text': 'Puedes dar tu consentimiento de manera individual a cada partner. Ver la lista de todos los propósitos para los cuales utilizan tus datos para tener más información. En algunos casos, las empresas pueden revelar que usan tus datos sin pedir tu consentimiento, en función de intereses legítimos. Puedes hacer click en su política de privacidad para obtener más información al respecto o para rechazarlo.',
    'Vendor Screen Accept All Button Text': 'Aceptar todo',
    'Vendor Screen Reject All Button Text': 'Rechazar todo',
    'Vendor Screen Purposes Link Text': 'Ver porpósitos',
    'Vendor Screen Cancel Button Text': 'Cancelar',
    'Vendor Screen Save and Exit Button Text': 'Guardar y salir',
    'Initial Screen Body Text': 'Tanto nuestros partners como nosotros utilizamos cookies en nuestro sitio web para personalizar contenido y publicidad, proporcionar funcionalidades a las redes sociales, o analizar nuestro tráfico. Haciendo click consientes el uso de esta tecnologia en nuestra web. Puedes cambiar de opinion y personalizar tu consentimiento siempre que quieras volviendo a esta web',
    'Initial Screen Body Text Option': 1,
    'Publisher Name': 'NewEsc',
    'Min Days Between UI Displays': 564,
    'UI Layout': 'banner',
    'No Option': false,
    'Post Consent Page': 'https://newesc.com/politica-de-privacidad/',
});
</script>
<!-- End Quantcast Choice. Consent Manager Tag -->
   <style>
    .qc-cmp-button {
      background-color: #116fac !important;
      border-color: #116fac !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-button:hover {
      background-color: transparent !important;
      border-color: #116fac !important;
      color: #116fac !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-alt-action,
    .qc-cmp-link {
      color: #116fac !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-button {
      color: #ffffff !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-button.qc-cmp-secondary-button {
      color: #222222  !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-button.qc-cmp-button.qc-cmp-secondary-button:hover {
      color:#ffffff !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-button.qc-cmp-secondary-button {
      border-color: #222222  !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-button.qc-cmp-secondary-button:hover {
      background-color: #222222  !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-ui,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-main-messaging,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-messaging,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-beta-messaging,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-title,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-sub-title,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-purpose-info,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-table,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-table-header,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-vendor-list,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-vendor-list-title {
        color: #161616 !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-ui a,
    .qc-cmp-ui .qc-cmp-alt-action {
      color: #0d74af !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-ui {
        background-color: #f4f4f4 !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-publisher-purposes-table .qc-cmp-table-header {
      background-color: #fafafa !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-publisher-purposes-table .qc-cmp-table-row {
      background-color: #ffffff !important;
    }
    .qc-cmp-small-toggle.qc-cmp-toggle-on,
    .qc-cmp-toggle.qc-cmp-toggle-on {
        background-color: #11ac56 !important;
        border-color: #11ac56 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: In your web address provided I don't see blocked navigation.

Comment: The question now comes what version of browser you are running?